# Symfony2 alternative "external parameters" method, boolean values not possible

Tags: php, symfony

I am using the alternative method to define Symfony parameters as described here http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/configuration/external_parameters.html

My Virtual host file looks like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
.......
.......
SetEnv SYMFONY__DATABASE_DRIVER pdo_mysql
SetEnv SYMFONY__DATABASE_HOST 127.0.0.1
SetEnv SYMFONY__SOME_BOOLEAN true
```

The parameter "some_boolean" is been interrupted by Symfony as a string and not a boolean.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to use `1` or `0`.

Comment: 1 or 0 didnt work either. Just to clarify, here is my exact situation.


Virtual Host Config:

`SetEnv SYMFONY__DEBUG_TOOLBAR true`


config.yml:

`toolbar: "%debug_toolbar%"`


Symfony Error:

`Invalid type for path "web_profiler.toolbar". Expected boolean, but got string.`

Comment: Also tried  config.yml: `toolbar: %debug_toolbar%` (Without the quotes)

Comment: Docs don't say about type of external parameter :/ i think it's only string.

Comment: I suspect that the problem is actually occurring in config.yml. People using ini style configuration are also getting the same problem. https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/2219#issuecomment-2146023